# How to capture HTTP(S) traffic from and to a Java web application with Fiddler2 or similar tool?

Tags: java, capture, fiddler

I want to capture data that my web application sends and receives from a CAS server via HTTPS. I tried using Fiddler2, but couldn't make it capture traffic from Java web application. It seems I need to configure it to use Fiddler2 as a proxy. How do I do it correctly?

Some additional info. I have already imported Fiddler's certificate with keytool. Running web application on Tomcat 7. Using IntelliJ Idea.

Answer (score 9):

Run the JVM with these parameters:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=yourhostwithfiddler -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888
```

Alternately, you could set the Java default proxy through a GUI - see http://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml

Comment: Thanks for the GUI proxy setting tip, but I still could not capture any data from my web application. What should the value of "yourhostwithfiddler" be? A set it to localhost.

Comment: @Infeligo: Whatever host that runs an instance of Fiddler. If it's the same computer that runs your Java application, then `localhost` should work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Piskvor answer, make sure you configure Fiddler to capture the HTTPS traffic: Tools --> Fiddler Options --> HTTPS --> Capture HTTPS CONNECTs

Comment: Ah, good point. You may also want to *decrypt* them (by checking the next checkbox), but this will be more complicated (as Fiddler will essentially be a MITM proxy)

Comment: Just in case someone wants to decrypt the https connection. http://ofcode.blogspot.com/2012/07/intercepting-https-traffic-for-java.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use directly the settings screen:
"File / Settings...", then choose"IDE Settings / HTTP Proxy".
Then tick "Use proxy", "Host name": localhost, "Port number": 8888

Comment: which app do you configure this in?